# Can you upload custom html in subsite different from master page?

Tags: 2010, css, html

I have sharepoint 2010 with a masterpage template. I have a custom html/css naviation bar I want to add to my subsite only. Does the subsite have its own master page to upload its own html/css?

the html is custom navigation with icons and logo

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should stop master page inheritance and create a new master page for your sub site.